# Cannot scale or rotate geometry in object mode

Tags: modeling

I'm a Blender newbie and I've got a scene with lots of geometry in it, but now I can't scale or rotate anything. This also applies to new primitives. I've searched the web and this forum, but the only answer I've been able to find is the Manipulate Center Points button is enabled. But I'm using 2.8, and can't even find that button. All transforms are unlocked. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you accidentally enable **snapping option**? Or you lock the object in **outliner**?

Comment: No, snapping is off. And the all the objects are unlocked in the Outliner. This problem also applied to new geometry that was created - no ability to scale or rotate but translate was possible. I went around the problem by opening an earlier version of the file, but that problem is still a mystery.